# Cache writes on a RAID to SSD and only do one daily commit to HDD

Tags: debian, samba, cache, software-raid

I have a Debian 10.7 server at home with 3x8TB disks in a mdraid5 setup, kept with hd-idle at a 600s spindown time to reduce power usage. The only thing using the disks is a Samba server, which serves three Macs/Macbooks with TimeMachine.

So far so good but unfortunately TimeMachine makes hourly backups... and hourly disk wakeups as a result. Now, I have an old Samsung SSD flying around... is it possible to use the SSD as some sort of "cache" and only commit the writes of the day once at night, so that ideally there is only one disk spinup event a day?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do that with a Cronjob on Rsync or something of that effect. RDiff-Backups if your looking for a full blown backup solution.

Here what I would do...

1. Backup on the SSD
2. Nightly Rsync/RDiff/etc to the HDDs
3. HDDs will spins down as you expected and shouldn't be more than idling.
4. If your not using the HDDs other than to store data you could even rig up a script to mount and unmount them entirely during these times. If not when you need Samaba to "activate" them. Cutting power usages entirely except during absolute usages as such.

Comment: The SSD unfortunately is only a 120GB SSD - the backups in total are somewhat 6TB at the moment. No way to put these on the SSD... basically what I'd need is some sort of what Apple calls "Fusion Drive" - cache the most needed stuff on the SSD.

Comment: That's a real bummer indeed and I feels your pains. :( I wish I knew because frankly that might be of use for so many applications beside of this. :)